# UISegmentedControl image

Tags: image, uisegmentedcontrol

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the default segmented bar when I add my own images to the segments?  I have added 3 custom images to the uisegmentedcontrol but when i debug, the bar is still present in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the divider image using setDividerImage (and related) methods.